# Sample application for Microsoft PixelSense?

Tags: pixelsense

Do you guys came across any sample application (i need source code of the app) for Microsoft PixelSense in web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys after googling lot i have collected few useful links to start coding on surface environtment.

http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC17/#Page
http://ctlabs.blogspot.com/search/label/Surface
http://robertbunn.wordpress.com/2009/04/18/converting-wpf-apps-to-surface-apps-part-1/
http://www.aboutmicrosoftsurface.com/features-of-microsoft-surface.php

if you guys come across any useful post for surface please post your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the Surface SDK 1.0 which is not available thru an official source.

Comment: Hi Erlichmen,
       Thanks for your reply. I want to know is any boday writing on blogs how to do Surface apps in net? . I can bale to see some of the blogs in microsoft surface but i am not able to find any code samples. If you find any blogs are articles very useful for development please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can now download the Surface SDK with sample applications from the [Surface Partner site](http://partner.surface.com/en/Pages/default.aspx). If you have access to the [Surface Community site](http://community.surface.com/) there are more advanced applications without source there.

Comment: You can also download the surface SDK if you have msdn subscription. Also the Academic Alliance (MSDNAA) subscription (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic/dd795227.aspx) might get you there.